# Trouble for newbie with header code

Tags: wordpress

I'm a newbie to code and pretty well illiterate. I have inserted some code into my customized header file only to realize it was the wrong place.

I since received this error message when i try to get onto my website

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /home2/seth1/public_html/wp-content/themes/TESSERACT/inc/custom-header.php on line 151

After seeing this i downloaded filezilla and removed the code I had previously  inserted. This code wasn't on or near line 151 where the error was.

The website is sethslawnandgarden
and here is a link to my code pastebin.com/s7ePRE6Q

Comment: You should take your backup and simply replace your **../TESSERACT/inc/custom-header.php** file with the original or backup one.

Comment: Thank you, this worked great. cheers

Comment: Ok please close the post by vote & accept my below answer then :)
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This error says than your js code incude before jquery library.
try add parameter array('jquery') in 
wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array('jquery') ); or in file (or in  tags) transfer all code to

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function( $ ) {
//your code
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take your backup and simply replace your ../TESSERACT/inc/custom-header.php file with the original or backup one.